# Finding an ObservableCollection for given/dynamic type via reflection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, types, observablecollection

I have a Class with several ObservableCollections for different types. Now, I want to find the correct Collection for a given type via reflection, because I don't want to build an if-monster which I have to update every time I add another Collection.

This method was the first step:

```
public ObservableCollection<T> GetObservableCollectionForType<T>()
{

   foreach (PropertyInfo info in this.GetType().GetProperties())
   {

      if (info.GetGetMethod() != null && info.PropertyType == typeof(ObservableCollection<T>))
         return (ObservableCollection<T>)this.GetType().GetProperty(info.Name).GetValue(this, null);                   

   }

   return null;

}
```

Now, I need a second method, which accepts a concrete object as parameter and finds the correct Collection. Somehow like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<T> GetObservableCollectionFor(object sObject)
{

   Type wantedType = sObject.GetType();

   foreach (PropertyInfo info in this.GetType().GetProperties())
   {

     if (info.GetGetMethod() != null && info.PropertyType == ObservableCollection<wantedType>)
        return this.GetType().GetProperty(info.Name).GetValue(this, null);

   }

   return null;

}
```

Any ideas how to realize this?

**Update**:

A working solution:

```
public object GetObservableCollectionFor(object sObject)
{

   Type wantedType = sObject.GetType();

   foreach (PropertyInfo info in this.GetType().GetProperties())
   {

      if (info.GetGetMethod() != null && info.PropertyType == typeof(ObservableCollection<>).MakeGenericType(new[]{wantedType}))
         return this.GetType().GetProperty(info.Name).GetValue(this, null);

   }

   return null;

}
```

This will return the correct collection as object. I still don't know how to cast to the correct generic type, but casting to IList is enough for adding and removing.

Comment: Can you not just add an explicit cast as per my updated answer and leave the return type as ObservableCollection<T>?

Comment: Seems like the compiler does not accept 'ObservableCollection<T>' as return type, as far as the methodcall provides no <T>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When comparing the type of the property, it looks like you need to add a call to MakeGenericType() on the ObservableCollection type.  Haven't tested this but maybe something like...

```
public ObservableCollection<T> GetObservableCollectionFor(object sObject)
{

   Type wantedType = sObject.GetType();

   foreach (PropertyInfo info in this.GetType().GetProperties())
   {

     if (info.GetGetMethod() != null && info.PropertyType == typeof(ObservableCollection<>).MakeGenericType(new[]{Type.GetType(wantedType)})

        return (ObservableCollection<T>)this.GetType().GetProperty(info.Name).GetValue(this, null);

   }

   return null;

}
```

**Edit**
To avoid overhead boxing with value types, the above method definition could be improved by changing the parameter type from object to type T

```
public ObservableCollection<T> GetObservableCollectionFor(T sObject)
```

Comment: Thanks, but seems like the compiler does not accept a usage of typeof(ObservableCollection) without T-argument

Comment: @MartinTausch, I have made an edit. I forgot to add the angled brackets for generic types.

Comment: Ah, well. Now I can compile. But he still doesn't accept the T in declaration of returning value. I could return as object instead, but don't know how to cast correct then...