# Casting reflected property to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, observablecollection

I have a C# program in which I get values of properties in a class by means of reflection. Some of these properties are ObservableCollections. I'm using those specifically because I want to access the `CollectionChanged` event.

Here's how I get the property:

```
var o = propertyInfo.GetValue(this, null);
```

Now I know (from other conditions in the code) that this is an `ObservableCollection`. But I can't just use `o.CollectionChanged` because the compiler doesn't see it that way.

What I figured I should do was to cast `o` to an `ObservableCollection`. Something like this perhaps:

```
(o as ObservableCollection<>).CollectionChanged...
```

But unfortunately that won't work. I get an error between the angular brackets that says 'type expected'.

Can I get the type within `o`? Sure, I can use `GetGenericArguments`, which returns the type of the items in the `ObservableCollection`. But the problem is, I can't put that type between the angular brackets when casting - it just won't allow it.

How can I do this?

I am aware there is another similar question to this, but it does not address my question and the solutions do not answer my question, as far as I can see. I also think it would be difficult to ask more about that, since the question is over five years old. Furthermore, this guy wants to get a collection based on an object he has and the solutions reflect that. His 'working solution' at the bottom of his question, which works for him, does not address my problem at all. You might think they're similar if you don't read closely, but they're not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding an ObservableCollection for given/dynamic type via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782154/finding-an-observablecollection-for-given-dynamic-type-via-reflection)

Comment: Another option is to just try converting to the type when you know the type; for example if you have T do this.  ```if (o is ObservableCollection<T> collection)```

Comment: You could avoid this by casting to [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged?view=netcore-3.1). The interface and event itself aren't actually generic.